How to fetch data for all tokens listed on Raydium in the past month?
For some reason, I've recently taken on a task that requires me to collect data on all tokens listed on Raydium in the past month and perform analysis. However, this is my first time dealing with blockchains, and to be honest, I only had a very basic understanding of blockchain and cryptocurrencies before this.
I've spent some time trying to grasp how the Solana blockchain and Raydium work, but I'm still unclear on the most efficient way to get this data. I've come across some APIs like api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, Raydium, DexScreener, Birdeye, etc., but I'm puzzled about which API would be the easiest to use for what I need, and how to actually use these APIs. Their descriptions contain some terms that I don't quite understand.
Could someone provide a simple guide on how to approach this? I would be incredibly grateful! I think this might be a very basic question, but I am truly a complete beginner in this field. It would be even better if you could share some code examples.
Thank you so much for any help you can provide!
